# Using “before” for relationships other than time

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning, adverbs

As I read books and posts on G+, I am confused from using of some adverbs of place and time.

And why? Because some ones I have *paired* with time (for example before) are used as adverb of place.

For example

> The Church of Our Lady Before Týn

But in my opinion it should be

> The Church of Our Lady in the front of Týn

because *Týn* is a place and the church stands near this place — and really it stands in front of it, in the direction of the Old town square (*Staroměstské náměstí*).

So, what are the rules for using of *before*? Is the first translation correct?

Comment: Before actually has a secondary meaning: "in front of." which isn't related to time. So your two sentences are semantically identical.

Answer (score 4):

In modern English, *before* most often means “earlier in time”. But it can also have other meanings, mostly (but not exclusively) in formal or old-fashioned language. Even learners' dictionaries such as [*Cambridge*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/before_1) and [*Merriam-Webster*](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/before) list them. One of these meanings is the spatial meaning “in front of”. Given that the church is an old and respected building, it makes sense to use a formal and slightly old-fashioned way of naming it.

The original Czech uses the preposition *před*. I don't know Czech so I don't know what nuances this has but I do see that [Czech Wiktionary](https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C5%99ed) lists “before, in front of” for one of the meanings of that preposition.

It's a common trait of many languages, including English, Czech and Latin¹, to have a preposition meaning both “earlier in time” and “nearer to me in space”.

By the way, *before* is a preposition, here. The same word can also be used as an adverb; when it's an adverb, the meanings other than “earlier in time” are rare.

¹  <sub>*ante*, found as a prefix in some English words, with either a time meaning (*antedate*, *antecedent*) or a space meaning (*antechamber*, *anterior*).</sub>

Comment: Yes, you are right that Czech word _před_ has multiple nuances - that it may mean before in time like place. Exact meaning is given by words following in sentence, mostly defining if it is place or time.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the [established translation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_Our_Lady_before_T%C3%BDn).

"Before" can relate to a place too. For example, "stand before the Lord", "appear before the court".