# Using the preposition "before" for a location

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

I have just arrived to my friend's house and he would like to know where I parked my automobile and asks me:

> **A)** Where did you park your car? 
>   **B)** I parked it **before** the post office.

Would you please tell me if the usage of "before" in my example is correct.[image]

Comment: I think when ***before*** is used as a *spatial* rather than a *temporal* reference (as in [*"How dare you fart before the Queen!" - "I'm sorry, I didn't know it was her turn!"*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128060/god-bless-you-equivalent-for-fart/305906#comment264382_128064)) it's usually relative to a (potentially mobile) ***person*** *(**before** = **in the presence of**)*, rather than a "fixed location" such as the Post Office. But your example is ambiguous, in that it might mean ***before I got to** the PO* or *[physically] **in front of** the PO*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using “before” for relationships other than time](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85380/using-before-for-relationships-other-than-time)

Comment: You could say "I parked it right by the post office - on the street facing side" or "It is parked on the main lane by the post office".

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers, but I exactly need to say: "**before I got to the PO**". If "before" doesn't work here, then how shall I say that?

Comment: But @AIQ "by" here mans "near to", whereas I need to imply "before we get to the post office". I think "by" is more ambiguous in the sense I meed, while it can mean "after" too.

Comment: To force the "temporal" interpretation, just say something like *I parked it **before I reached / got to** the post office*.

Comment: Would it sound natural @FumbleFingers?

Comment: Which side of the street are you driving on in this diagram?  In the U.S., you would be driving to the left on the top lane, and you would say "just past the post office."

Answer (score 2):

To me, this does not sound very natural. It would be better to say something like:

- I parked it near to the post office
- I parked it next to the post office
- I parked it at the side of the post office
- I parked it by the post office.
- I parked it just past/ **just before** the post office.

Comment: Excellent answer @books4languahes.com. Just out of curiosity, what about when I park my car "**after**" the post office? I think all your offered sentences would be the same, except for the last one which would be "**just after**". Right? I wonder if "**just past**" means "after".

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly grammatical, but a bit ambiguous. Your friend would need to know which way you were travelling to work out which side 'before' was. If you said 'the other side of the Post Office' then in context I think that's unambiguous: from where you were when you said it, it can only mean one side.

The problem with both phrases is not grammatic, but that both 'before' and 'other side' are relative, and without more information - which way you were coming from, where you were when you said it - the side meant cannot be inferred.

Also, 'before' could mean the side of the Post Office you would reach before the Post Office when going there from where you are now.

Comment: Well @simon at rcl I wonder whether it would help to clear up this ambiguity if I add to the pic's details in the manner that it can show the traffic direction.

Comment: @A-friend Maybe, but unless you're showing it to who-ever you're talking to you need to describe it in words. You could say 'It's by the Post Office just to the east/west/north/south', or you could say 'it's to the left of the Post Office looking at from from across the street '.

Comment: Aha, I see @simon at rcl. Just, I would be please to know about your opinion regarding: "I parked it just past/ just before the post office." Does it still sound ambiguous to you?

Comment: Yes it is. Is 'Just Passed' on the left or on the right? Before and Passed need a point (the example has one) and a direction. 'Passed' in one direction is 'before' in the other. (PS 'Past' is a time-reference: 'It happened many years in the past'; 'Passed' is a location-reference and that's what you need.)

Comment: So it would be logically clear while there is a two way street and you could have not been arrived from an opposite side!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. My point is that you could have arrived from either direction in a two way street. Also, before and passed could refer not to the direction of travel but from where you are now. You come from the left in your diagram and part just before the PO (including 'come from the left' defines which side you parked). You continue to the left. Relative to where you are now talking to your friend. You could use passed to describe the location of your car relative your location. Or you could say 'the other side of the PO from here' and not use before/passed at all.